# General Tree data structure problem involving recursion

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, recursive-datastructures

I am struggling with an exercise. So given in a general tree data structure the root of the tree and a token ( the value you need to search the nodes). I have to create a recursive function that takes the root of the tree and the key to search for and thee function should return the parent of the node where we find the key.

Class of the node is this :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Node {
    int key;
     ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    public  boolean hasChildren(){
        if(children.size() !=0){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I tired doing level order :

```
static Node findParent(Node root,int token){
    Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.add(root);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        Node temp = queue.poll();
        if(temp.hasChildren()){
            for(int i=0;i<temp.children.size()){
                if()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but i dont know how to do the if condition to return the parent, and after finding the parent it will add the childrens in the arraylist of the nodes to the queue.

Comment: What should the function return if the root has the value, since it has no parent?

Comment: In that case, it would return null as the parent.

Answer (score 0):

At each level, p is the parent and c is a child of p.  If c matched token, then we return the parent p.  Otherwise, we add c to the queue to be processed later.  If all the nodes are visited, then there's no match and we return null.

```
  static Node parent(Node root,int token){
    Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.add(root);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
      Node p = queue.poll();
      for(Node c: p.children){
        if(c.key == token) return p;
        queue.add(c);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```